# Passing a variable to an included Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'd like to pass a variable to an included Ansible playbook as follows:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_group: foo

- include: site.yml hosts={{ my_group }}
```

Then, in `site.yml`...

```
---
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
...
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying that `my_group` is undefined in `site.yml`. [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) do say that:

> Note that you cannot do variable substitution when including one playbook inside another.

Is this my case? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Why don't you just go `- include: site.yml hosts=foo`? Where else are you using `my_group`? Or you could use a host_var for localhost.

Comment: The first playbook actually deploys a server and puts its id into a variable. After the deployment, I want to run the playbook to setup the application stack but only limit it to the newly created machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax, but `my_group` has to be defined at the global level. Now it's local to the first play - it's even clear from the indentation.

You can confirm this by running your playbook with `--extra-vars my_group=foo`.

---

But generally what you seem to want to achieve is done using in-memory inventory files and [`add_host` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html). Take this as an example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    target_host: foo
    some_other_variable: bar
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamically_created_hosts
        some_other_variable: "{{ some_other_variable }}"

- include: site.yml
```

with `site.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: dynamically_created_hosts
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: some_other_variable
```

I added `some_other_variable` to answer the question from your comment "*how do I make a variable globally available from inside a play*". It's not global, but it's passed to another play as a "hostvar".

---

<sup>From what I see (and I can't explain why) in Ansible >=2.1.1.0, there must be an inventory file specified for the dynamic in-memory inventory to work. In older versions it worked with Ansible executed ad hoc, without an inventory file, but now you must run `ansible-playbook` with `-i inventory_file` or have an inventory file defined through `ansible.cfg`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks - how do I make a variable globally available from inside a play then?

Comment: Afaik, you pass a variable from a play to another playbook only by using in-memory inventory file (on top of what I mentioned above), but then you'd already use in-memory inventory for the real thing (what I mentioned above). I'm trying to write an example now... But basically what you seem to want is in the docs.

Comment: @jamix I have finished the answer. There was an unexpected hurdle on the way.

Comment: Thank you. You were right about the variable scope but we solved this by referencing `hostvars['localhost']['my_group']` in the included play instead. We are using a dynamic Digital Ocean inventory already so the specific `add_host` solution probably wouldn't work for us.